# How can I get this variable passed to another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js

I am trying to pass the client value to another file.

I am using express to create a web server that works with my discord bot, and want to do something on a post request to an endpoint.
When the endpoint receives a post request with a user id, the bot should send them a message.

```js
// index.js

const client = new Client(etc etc);
const routes = require('./routes.js');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + PORT);
});
app.use(bodyParser.json(), routes, limiter);
client.login(token).then(() => {console.info('Logged in.');});
module.exports = { client };
```

In the index.js file, the server is created, along with various other command handling things that are unrelated.

```js
// routes.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { invite, topggAuth } = require('./config.json');
const client = require('./index.js');
const vote = require('./events/vote.js');
router.route('/api/tggwh').post((req, res) => {
    if (req.header('authorization') === topggAuth) {
        vote.execute(client, req.body);
        res.status(200).end();
    }
    else {
        console.log('Unauthorized vote request attempt.');
        res.send('Unauthorized');
        res.status(401).end();
    }
});
```

Routing seems to work fine, it matches the auth header to the key in the config file, then moves on to the vote handler.

```js
// vote.js

const { logUsage } = require('../functions.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'vote', // name, duh
    async execute(client, data) { // stuff to do
        try {
            const targetUser = await client.users.cache.get(data.user);
            await targetUser.send('Thank you for voting!');
            logUsage({ name: 'vote' });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Whoops! Something went wrong while thanking a vote.');
            console.error(error);
        }

    },
};
```

This is where the error comes in.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
    at Object.execute (/home/ubuntu/Harold/events/vote.js:7:42)
    at /home/ubuntu/Harold/routes.js:43:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/ubuntu/Harold/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
```

I think this means that client is passed through, but client.users is not.
How can I pass client through to vote.js after its been called by the post request?

Comment: `client` is not defined in your `vote.js`.

Comment: You might wanna change the line `client.login(token).then(() => console.info('Logged in.'));` (adding the "() =>") because instead it will always say "Logged in" and not wait for the logging to success

Comment: Alright @MalikLahlou I've done that.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have edited the post to display the entire file and module.

Comment: What exactly is `client = new Client(etc etc)`? Does this already contain `client.users`?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen that is defining the client, where `etc etc` is are the intents and partials and stuff.

Comment: Where is `client.users` set? That occurs nowhere in the code you shared.

Comment: users is part of client, have you used discord.js?